# Broken closure - please help me fix it

Tags: javascript, closures

in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584397/javascript-countdown-clock/4584501) I have posted this code. It almost works, but the counter doesn't.

Can we fix it? (no jQuery, please)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var intervals = [];
var counters = {
  "shoes":{"id":"shoe1","minutes":1,"seconds":5},
  "trousers":{"id":"trouser1","minutes":10,"seconds":0}
}; // generate this on the server and note there is no comma after the last item
window.onload = function() {
  for (var el in counters) { countdown(counters[el]) };
}

function countdown(element) {
    intervals[element.id] = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element.id);
        var minutes = element.minutes;
        var seconds = element.seconds;
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
                clearInterval(intervals[element.id]);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }
        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
        el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
shoes: <span id="shoe1"></span><br />
trousers: <span id="trouser1"></span><br />
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very descriptive. Can you elaborate on what is and what isn't working?

Comment: Load it and see it not updating the time. Like Jon did :)

Comment: Just a comment. You should use `var intervals = {};` instead of `var intervals = [];`, because you are using it like a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: Associative array are also arrays, no?

Comment: @mplungjan: I can do that, yes, but it shouldn't be necessary. I'm not dissing you or your question, but merely wanting to point out that you should provide as much info as possible when asking questions.

Comment: I agree and would normally do so, but the code was so simple and I felt that _but the counter doesn't._ was enough to explain my issue

Comment: @mplungjan: associative arrays do not exist in javascript. Arrays are objects, and every object in javascript is dynamically typed, and can be expanded. As such, you can add properties such as 'shoes' and 'trousers' to any object, even an array. `intervals['shoes']` is the exact same thing as `intervals.shoes`. They're just properties on objects, and since that's all you want, you should stick with `{}`, because you won't be using anything that you'll need an array for, such as `length`, `push()`, `sort()`, etc.

Comment: Hmm, seems I need to change old habits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to take the `minutes` and `seconds` variable declarations out of the inner function, like this:

```
function countdown(element) {
    var minutes = element.minutes;
    var seconds = element.seconds;

    intervals[element.id] = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element.id);
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
                clearInterval(intervals[element.id]);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }
        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
        el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

When you call `countdown`, you want to fetch the initial values for each countdown and then slowly decrease them (closure makes sure that the values will stay available as long as the anonymous function requires them). What you were doing before was reset the countdown values at the start of each tick, so the countdown never had a chance to... well, count down.

**Update:**

If you need to update the values inside `window.counters` while the countdowns are active (although I don't see why you would want to do that; if you want to do anything meaningful with the "current" countdown values, just do it inside the anonymous function), you can simply add this at the end:

```
var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
seconds--;

// ADD THIS:
element.minutes = minutes;
element.seconds = seconds;
```

Comment: VERY close to grokking closures now :) Thanks!

Comment: This works, but doesn't update the original member variables.

Comment: In this case that is ok I would think. If the member values would survive a reload, then it might be important, if not, not.

Comment: @nikc: True, but they don't need to be updated no matter what you want to do. I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: @mplungjan: It's fine if it's fine, I just wanted to point the fact out so it doesn't jump back and surprise you :-)

Comment: @Jon: it doesn't matter in the context that we're aware of, but we don't know whether the same data is used elsewhere also.

Comment: @nikc: if the values matter, do whatever matters inside the anon function. It would be a bad idea to have code that does stuff depending on one global value spread over multiple functions.

Comment: @Jon: not necessarily. Consider if this was a game and the countdown was until your money runs out, which causes the game to end. Another concurrent event adds money to your balance. How is this irrelevant?

Comment: @nikc: You said it yourself: concurrent *event*. It would be really bad design to implement that scenario as async polling (which is what is being discussed here) instead of a publisher/observer system.

Comment: @Jon: sure, not best practice, but the nature of JavaScript makes it safe. No two events will ever occur at the same time, async or other.

Comment: @nikc: I don't see why we should keep arguing. I 'm not saying it could not work. I 'm just saying I wouldn't do it, and why.

Comment: I would want the member values to be decreased iff they survive a reload. I would not want the counter to start from scratch in this particular case - the original question this code comes from was a sort of EBAY "time to purchase" thing. I would expect the asker to probably need to harden the end time instead of time-to-live :)

Answer (score 4):

Please check this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var intervals = [];
        var counters = {
          "shoes":{"id":"shoe1","minutes":1,"seconds":5},
          "trousers":{"id":"trouser1","minutes":10,"seconds":0}
        }; // generate this on the server and note there is no comma after the last item
        window.onload = function() {
          for (var el in counters) { countdown(counters[el]) };
        }

        function countdown(element) {
            intervals[element.id] = setInterval(function() {
                var el = document.getElementById(element.id);
                var minutes = element.minutes;
                var seconds = element.seconds;

                if(seconds == 0) {
                    if(minutes == 0) {
                        el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
                        clearInterval(intervals[element.id]);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        minutes--;
                        seconds = 60;
                    }
                }
                if(minutes > 0) {
                    var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
                } else {
                    var minute_text = '';
                }
                var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
                el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
                seconds--;

                element.seconds = seconds;
                element.minutes = minutes;
            }, 1000);
        }
        </script>
        shoes: <span id="shoe1"></span><br />
        trousers: <span id="trouser1"></span><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Working solution is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lwxhx/).

EDIT: There was a minor issue with the script. I've fixed it.

After recalculating the `seconds` and `minutes` you have to set the new values back in the `element` object.

Comment: Thanks - I did try something similar, but Jon's is what I wanted since it is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You're decrementing the wrong variable inside your interval callback. Instead of doing `seconds--` and `minutes--` you need to reference the `element` members.

```
intervals[element.id] = setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById(element.id);

    if(element.seconds == 0) {
        if(element.minutes == 0) {
            el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
            clearInterval(intervals[element.id]);
            return;
        } else {
            element.minutes--;
            element.seconds = 60;
        }
    }
    if(element.minutes > 0) {
        var minute_text = element.minutes + (element.minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
    } else {
        var minute_text = '';
    }
    var second_text = element.seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
    el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + element.seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
    element.seconds--;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It is very close to what I had before I made a mess of the closure version. I think the best is Jon's plus his additions. Clearer!

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers you've been given so far fail to handle one simple fact: `setInterval` does **not** happen reliably at the time you set. It can be delayed or even *skipped* if the browser is busy doing something else. This means you can't rely on your update function to decrement the number of seconds left, you'll start drifting from reality very quickly. Maybe that's okay, maybe not. There's no *need* for it, in any case: Just calculate when the timeout occurs (e.g., a minute and five seconds from now for your "shoes" counter), and then at each update, calculate how long you have left. That way if an interval got dropped or something, you won't drift; you're deferring the computer's clock.

Here's a procedural version:

```
// Note that to prevent globals, everything is enclosed in
// a function. In this case, we're using window.onload, but
// you don't have to wait that long (window.onload happens
// *very* late, after all images are loaded).
window.onload = function() {

  // Our counters
  var counters = {
    "shoes":{
      "id": "shoe1",
      "minutes": 1,
      "seconds":5
    },
    "trousers":{
      "id": "trouser1",
      "minutes": 10,
      "seconds":0
    }
  };

  // Start them
  var name;
  for (name in counters) {
    start(counters[name]);
  }

  // A function for starting a counter
  function start(counter) {
    // Find the time (in ms since The Epoch) at which
    // this item expires
    counter.timeout = new Date().getTime() +
                      (((counter.minutes * 60) + counter.seconds) * 1000);

    // Get this counter's target element
    counter.element = document.getElementById(counter.id);
    if (counter.element) {
      // Do the first update
      tick(counter);

      // Schedule the remaining ones to happen *roughly*
      // every quarter second. (Once a second will look
      // rough).
      counter.timer = setInterval(function() {
        tick(counter);
      }, 250);
    }
  }

  // Function to stop a counter
  function stop(counter) {
    if (counter.timer) {
      clearInterval(counter.timer);
      delete counter.timer;
    }
    delete counter.element;
  }

  // The function called on each "tick"
  function tick(counter) {
    var remaining, str;

    // How many seconds left?
    remaining = Math.floor(
      (counter.timeout - new Date().getTime()) / 1000
    );

    // Same as last time?
    if (remaining != counter.lastRemaining) {
      // No, do an update
      counter.lastRemaining = remaining;
      if (remaining <= 0) {
        // Done! Stop the counter.
        str = "done";
        alert("Stopped " + counter.id);
        stop(counter);
      }
      else {
        // More than a minute left?
        if (remaining >= 120) {
          // Yup, output a number
          str = Math.floor(remaining / 60) + " minutes";
        }
        else if (remaining >= 60) {
          // Just one minute left
          str = "one minute";
        }
        else {
          // Down to seconds!
          str = "";
        }

            // Truncate the minutes, just leave seconds (0..59)
        remaining %= 60;

        // Any seconds?
        if (remaining > 0) {
          // Yes, if there were minutes add an "and"
          if (str.length > 0) {
            str += " and ";
          }

          // If only one second left, use a word; else, 
          // a number
          if (remaining === 1) {
            str += "one second";
          }
          else {
            str += Math.floor(remaining) + " seconds";
              }
        }

        // Finish up
        str += " left";
      }

      // Write to the element
      counter.element.innerHTML = str;
    }
  }

};​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ujuzo5)

Here's an OOP version (using the module pattern so `Counter` can have [**named** functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) and a private one [`tick`]):

```
// A Counter constructor function
var Counter = (function() {
  var p;

  // The actual constructor (our return value)
  function Counter(id, minutes, seconds) {
    this.id = id;
    this.minutes = minutes || 0;
    this.seconds = seconds || 0;
  }

      // Shortcut to the prototype
  p = Counter.prototype;

  // Start a counter
  p.start = Counter_start;
  function Counter_start() {
    var me = this;

    // Find the time (in ms since The Epoch) at which
    // this item expires
    this.timeout = new Date().getTime() +
                      (((this.minutes * 60) + this.seconds) * 1000);

    // Get this counter's target element
    this.element = document.getElementById(this.id);
    if (this.element) {
      // Do the first update
      tick(this);

      // Schedule the remaining ones to happen *roughly*
      // every quarter second. (Once a second will look
      // rough).
      this.timer = setInterval(function() {
        tick(me);
      }, 250);
    }
  }

  // Stop a counter
  p.stop = Counter_stop;
  function Counter_stop() {
    if (this.timer) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      delete this.timer;
    }
    delete this.element;
  }

  // The function we use to update a counter; not exported
  // on the Counter prototype because we only need one for
  // all counters.
  function tick(counter) {
    var remaining, str;

    // How many seconds left?
    remaining = Math.floor(
      (counter.timeout - new Date().getTime()) / 1000
    );

    // Same as last time?
    if (remaining != counter.lastRemaining) {
      // No, do an update
      counter.lastRemaining = remaining;
      if (remaining <= 0) {
        // Done! Stop the counter.
        str = "done";
        alert("Stopped " + counter.id);
        stop(counter);
      }
      else {
        // More than a minute left?
        if (remaining >= 120) {
          // Yup, output a number
          str = Math.floor(remaining / 60) + " minutes";
        }
        else if (remaining >= 60) {
          // Just one minute left
          str = "one minute";
        }
        else {
          // Down to seconds!
          str = "";
        }

        // Truncate the minutes, just leave seconds (0..59)
        remaining %= 60;

        // Any seconds?
        if (remaining > 0) {
          // Yes, if there were minutes add an "and"
          if (str.length > 0) {
            str += " and ";
          }

          // If only one second left, use a word; else, 
          // a number
          if (remaining === 1) {
            str += "one second";
          }
          else {
            str += Math.floor(remaining) + " seconds";
          }
        }

        // Finish up
        str += " left";
      }

      // Write to the element
      counter.element.innerHTML = str;
    }
  }

  // Return the constructor function reference. This
  // gets assigned to the external var, which is how
  // everyone calls it.
  return Counter;
})();

// Note that to prevent globals, everything is enclosed in
// a function. In this case, we're using window.onload, but
// you don't have to wait that long (window.onload happens
// *very* late, after all images are loaded).
window.onload = function() {

  // Our counters
  var counters = {
    "shoes":    new Counter("shoe1", 1, 5),
    "trousers": new Counter("trouser1", 10, 0)
  };

  // Start them
  var name;
  for (name in counters) {
    counters[name].start();
  }

};​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ujuzo5/2)

[More about closures here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

Comment: Actually I knew this and have done what you suggest about not relying on the interval in the past. Thanks for reminding me and for a good OO example. Not sure why you need to delete timer and element - garbage collection?

Comment: @mplungjan: It's important not to have a JavaScript object holding a reference to a DOM element unnecessarily (particularly on IE), and since I don't need either of those properties any more at that point, `delete` seemed the natural thing to do. I could have just assigned `undefined` to them or something, but why not completely clean up. :-)

Comment: Here is a jQuery version: http://jsbin.com/oyoba3/edit the actual discussion is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584397/javascript-countdown-clock/4584501

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd make your code a lot cleaner and save you some `if`s if you would keep the timeout in code as seconds, rather than minutes and seconds:

```
var intervals = [];
var counters = {
  "shoes":{"id":"shoe1","seconds":65},
  "trousers":{"id":"trouser1","seconds":600}
}; // generate this on the server and note there is no comma after the last item

window.onload = function() {
  for (var el in counters) { countdown(counters[el]) };
}

function countdown(element) {
    intervals[element.id] = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element.id);

        if(element.seconds == 0) {
            el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
            clearInterval(intervals[element.id]);
            return;
        }

        var minutes = (element.seconds - (element.seconds % 60)) / 60;
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }

        var second_text = (element.seconds%60) > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
        el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + (element.seconds%60) + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';

        element.seconds--;

    }, 1000);
}​
```

(I'd post as a comment if it weren't for all the code...)

Comment: Yeah, but that was code not optimised from the other question. My problem was the closure. Thanks