# Javascript Closure technique

Tags: javascript

1. I have an object which creates a slideshow.
2. I want to have several slideshows on a page
3. I have an event handler for slideshow element inside it
4. I want the event handler to know which slideshow object has created an item clicked

-

```
slideshow=function(){

   var g = document.createElement(...);

   ...

   g.onclick = f1;

   f1 = function(slideshow_instance, event) {
      //EXPLAIN ME HOW TO GET THE slideshow_instance
   }

}

var sl1 = new slideshow();
var sl2 = new slideshow();
```

Clicking on an element slideshow has created should return either

> sl1

or

> sl2

I explain well?

Comment: Where is the slideshow_instance exactly created?

Comment: Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584845/broken-closure-please-help-me-fix-it/4585189#4585189

Comment: @Epeli the slideshow_instance is the same as this keyword... But I can't use it inside an event handler

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/js-var-self-this

Comment: You should write slideshow variable with capital S so that we can know that it is the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, use: `this`.

Longer answer, what you want is:

```
slideshow=function(){
   /* ... */

   var self = this;    

   f1 = function(event) {
      // do stuff with self.
   }

}
```

The reason you need to point to `this` using `self` is that event handlers will change the meaning of `this` when they are called. But at the time the object is created `this` properly refer to the correct object (an instance of slideshow). The reason we can access the self variable during event callback is because it has been captured by a closure.

Feel free to google or search on stackoverflow any word/terminology from the above description if you need further explanation.

Comment: +1 for being a little cleaner and easier to read than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
slideshow=function(){

   var g = document.createElement(...);
   g._objRef = this;

   ...

   g.onclick = f1;

   f1 = function(event) {
      alert(this._objRef);
   }

}

var sl1 = new slideshow();
var sl2 = new slideshow();
```

A bit of a hack imo, but it should do the trick.

Comment: you both are good! The solution was so simple but I couldn't see it!

Comment: You could just use closure here instead of referring it via dom element (which can be even slow).