# Count Down Clock doesn't return when time ran out.

Tags: javascript

I'm using code from this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501353/494901

Basically when the timer ends, I want it to return true to my functions such that when it's over I can do stuff only after it's over. But the script is never returning, it ends, but it never returns back to the method it's called.

```
function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

    function twoDigits( n )
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            time = new Date( msLeft );
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) +
                ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
            setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById( elementName );
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    return updateTimer();
}
```

Comment: how exactly are you calling this method?

Comment: It's asynchronous! You never can return a value from a future computation. You just set up the timer to do something later, and return immediately from the `countdown` function - a better name would be "initCountdown"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass a callback function as such:

```
countdown("element-id",0,5, function() { alert('done!'); });

function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds, callback)
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

    function twoDigits( n )
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
            callback();
        } else {
            time = new Date( msLeft );
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) +
                ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
            setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById( elementName );
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    return updateTimer();
}
```