# Multiple elements with getElementById

Tags: javascript, mysql, getelementbyid

I hope someone can help me with this, what I am trying to do is showing a java-script element within multiple `<div>`s generated from a while loop ( from mysql).

I am using `getElementById` but I know that the `getElementById` element only gets the first `<div>` - I'm not really sure how to make it work for all `<div>`s.

Here is my code so far :

```
    <?php
    session_start();

     $server = '...';
     $user = '...';
     $pass = '...';
     $db = '...';

     // Connect to Database
     $result = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) 
     or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
     mysql_select_db($db) 
     or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());


    // No session variable, red from mysql
    $result=mysql_query("select * from players");
    $time=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $dateFormat = "d F Y -- g:i a";
    $targetDate = strtotime($time['time']);
    $_SESSION['targetDate'] = $targetDate;



    $actualDate = time();
    $secondsDiff = $actualDate - $targetDate;
    $remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
    $remainingHour    = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24))/60/60);
    $remainingMinutes = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-         ($remainingHour*60*60))/60);
    $remainingSeconds = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-    ($remainingHour*60*60))-($remainingMinutes*60));
    $actualDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$actualDate);
    $targetDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$targetDate);

    echo $actualDateDisplay;
    echo $targetDateDisplay;
    ?>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Untitled Document</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var days = <?php echo $remainingDay; ?>  
          var hours = <?php echo $remainingHour; ?>  
          var minutes = <?php echo $remainingMinutes; ?>  
          var seconds = <?php echo $remainingSeconds; ?> 
          function setCountDown ()
          {
              seconds++;
              if (seconds > 60){
                 minutes++;
                 seconds = 0
              }
              if (minutes > 60){
                  hours++;
                  minutes = 0
              }
              if (hours > 6){
                  hours = 0
              }
              document.getElementsByClassName("remain") = "  "+hours+" hr "+minutes+" min    "+seconds+" sec";
              SD=window.setTimeout( "setCountDown()", 1000 );
              if (minutes == '00' && seconds == '00') { 
                  seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD);
                  window.location = "result.php"
              } 

           }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body onLoad="setCountDown();">

<?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

        echo "<div class=\"remain\">";
        echo "$remainingHour h, $remainingMinutes min, $remainingSeconds s, ";
        echo "</div>";
        } 

?>
```

Comment: so use a different ID for every div. or switch to a css class instead of ids, e.g. `<div class="remain">` and `document.getElementsByClassName('remain')`.

Comment: I tried using document.getElementsByClassName('remain'), but i cannot get it to work.

Comment: gEBCN returns an array. you can **NOT** assign new values to a function result.

Comment: Thanks Marc, i updated the code - $result=mysql_query("select * from players"); - still not working.

Answer (score 2):

ID's must be unique according to HTML standards:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Try setting the class instead, which by searching will return an array of results. You can then iterate through these!

*edit:* Here's a little fiddle using `document.getElementsByClassName();`
https://jsfiddle.net/965zbf0m/

Comment: I tried using document.getElementsByClassName('remain'), but i cannot get it to work and <div class="remain"> but it is not working.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Are you trying `result[0]`?

Comment: i updated my code as i have it .. so you can se what i got

Comment: Right...so first you didn't do what I said about the array. Second, you can't just set the value like that, you need to look more into javascript and setting div values.

Comment: i am sorry, i am not sure, i understand what do you mean by trying result[0]

Comment: Like I said before, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some type of selector engine available...like jQuery?

If so, could you use classes instead of ids (that combination would return an array of selected objects).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("remain") = "  "+hours+" hr "+minutes+" min    "+seconds+" sec";
```

document.getElementsByClassName will return you an array of matching elements.  You then want to loop over them and update accordingly.  I think this should do the trick:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("remain");
for (var i = divs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  divs[i].innerHTML = "  "+hours+" hr "+minutes+" min    "+seconds+" sec";
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is kind of working .. but all the divs are showing the same value ( they should show different timelaps ).

Comment: Ah I see - I think you may need to refactor your JavaScript a fair bit to get the desired results.  May be worth looking at these existing SO answers - [JavaScript Countdown in Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182628/javasacript-countdown-timer-in-days-hours-minute-seconds) and [JavaScript Countdown Clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584397/javascript-countdown-clock)